# Mediaplayer info/warning (951, 0)

Tags: java, android

I want to play a HD video with the Mediaplayer, but only the audio works and I get the info/warning (951, 0).

This info/warning does not call the OnErrorListener (which would switch to a non HD-source). I don't want to trigger the switch at a warning, which meaning I don't know.

I already searched in the documentation of the mediaplayer.

Thank you for every help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on a Samsung Galaxy when the mp4 video I tried to play had these dimension: 1920 x 1080.

When I changed the width and height of the video to 1280 x 720 it worked.